# Accessing/importing user defined classes in jrxml

Tags: import, jasper-reports

Have anyone tried to import user defined classes in jasper report (.jrxml file)?
I want to use some (user defined) Util class inside my jasper report to cook some bean attributes. I am using Javabean datasource

Please let me know if you need further clarification.

syntax to import class is

```
<import value="java.util.HashMap"/>
```

I want to use

```
<import value="mypackage.MyUtil" />
 ....
 ....
<field name="myVar" class="java.lang.String">
    <fieldDescription><![CDATA[MyUtil.cook(myData)]]>
    </fieldDescription>
</field>
```

The simple definition for MyUtil.java could be

```
package mypackage;
public class MyUtil
{
    public static String cook(String data)
    {
        return data + "_cooked";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think I should have tried sufficiently before asking this.

There is nothing extra needed apart from 
There are two sections in jrxml:
1. Defining fields from javabean source
2. Using fields defined in step 1. to populate values in detail band

I was trying to cook the value of javabean members even before they are used to create fields
So, jasper was trying to parse that 'expression' as javabean member.

Following is wrong

```
<field name="myVar" class="java.lang.String">
     <fieldDescription><![CDATA[MyUtil.cook(myData)]]>
     </fieldDescription>
</field>
```

When I used the Util class on field value, it worked.

```
<textField>
    <reportElement x="200" y="0" width="100" height="13"/>
    <textElement/>
    <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String">
         <![CDATA[MyUtil.cook($F{myVar})]]>
    </textFieldExpression>
</textField>
```

Thanks
Nayn

Comment: +1 for self learning. In cases like this you see how much better it is to use iReport.

Comment: yeah.. I love iReport. But unfortunately it doesn't work for my javabean datasource. For some unknown reasons, it doesn't allow me to create javabean datasource. "General exception : Null" is what i get. My java beans have field enum inside it apart from normal getter/setter for fields. The fields enum is used similar to java reflection to access field names programmatically wherever required. It is faster than reflection.

Comment: Ehm, perhaps you can ask another question for the datasource problem ? It is a way better approach to have things pre-compiled (in case you don't generate them dynamically)

Answer (score 4):

You have to set the `classpath` in your iReport. It depends on its version, but is generally under `Settings/Classpath`

Comment: well, then it should just work. What does the compiler tell you?

Comment: net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Error retrieving field value from bean : WireServiceUtil.getLinkedWires(wireRelationships) ....
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: Unknown property 'WireServiceUtil'.

To put further light on this, 'WireServiceUtil' is contained in another jar than the one where jrxml resides. But it is on classpath

Comment: That's odd. it should work. Try importing the WireServiceUtil in the class where you compile. Also check if the variable you are passing to the method really exists.

Comment: The jrxml files are inside a jar? how are you compiling them?

Comment: Mine is a web application, where jar gets exploded in tomcat, the jrxml compilation happens at run time.

>> JasperCompileManager.compileReportToFile(subReport)

Comment: jars getting exploded in tomcat is something strange. :)