# Get second value after split on Jasperreports

Tags: java, mysql, jasper-reports

I have a query returning data like this:

```
"1234 : description1,2345 : description2,4567 : description3"
```

I would like to fill a TextField on my reports like this:

```
description1,description2,description3
```

I've done this in Java but I don't know how to do it on my report(Jasperreports):

```
String eqps = "";
String[] pts = rs.getString("equipamento").split(",");
for (String c : pts) {
  eqps += c.split(":")[1].trim() + ",";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could simply create a utility class with a static method that takes a String value and returns a new String and put the logic you described in there.

Then, you import it in your JRXML and call it on the TextField expression. Just make sure you have this new class in the classpath when running the report. This post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1910939/accessing-importing-user-defined-classes-in-jrxml) briefly shows the syntax you need.